# Plotting data from two matrices on the same plot

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I need to plot data contained in the first 5 rows of two 21*120 matrices with the caveat that the data from one matrix should be plotted as lines and the data from the second - as circles on the same plot.

I'm not sure how to correctly reference x and y when trying to plot a matrix so I circumvented the issue by creating a bunch of vectors:

```matlab
x = 1:120;
y1 = V(1, :);
y2 = V(2, :);
y3 = V(3, :);
y4 = V(4, :);
y5 = V(5, :);
k1 = K(1, :);
k2 = K(2, :);
k3 = K(3, :);
k4 = K(4, :);
k5 = K(5, :);

% Plot combined figure with forward- and backtracked data
figure
plot(x, y1, 'r', x, y2, 'g', x, y3, 'b', x, y4, 'y', x, y5, 'c',...
     x, k1, 'ro', x, k2, 'go', x, k3,'bo', x, k4, 'yo', x, k5', 'co');
```

This works but there must be an easier way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to replace `y1`, `y2`, etc. with just the slice notation to take a slice of `V`. Then you don't need all those unnecessary variables.

```
plot(x, V(1, :), 'r', x, V(2, :), 'g', ... % and so on
```

But even better, define a cell array with the color names, and *use a loop!*

```
colors = {'r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c'};
figure;
hold on;

for ii=1:5
    plot(x, V(ii, :), 'color', colors{ii})
    plot(x, K(ii, :), 'color', colors{ii}, 'marker', 'o')
end
```

This way is much less tedious if you have many more columns to plot. It's also easy to extend if you have more columns!

```
nrows = size(V, 1);

colors = jet(nrows);
figure;
hold on;

for ii=1:nrows
    plot(x, V(ii, :), 'color', colors(ii, :))
    plot(x, K(ii, :), 'color', colors(ii, :), 'marker', 'o')
end
```

[`jet(n)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jet.html) returns a `n x 3` array where each row is a color in the jet colormap.

Comment: Thanks! Just a small correction: `plot(x, V(ii, :), 'color', colors{ii})` and similarly for the array of K.

Comment: Just another quick question. For the array of K it now plots a line with markers. How do I change it to only have markers and no line?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html or https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#namevaluepairs Add `'linestyle', 'none'` to the arguments you give to `plot`